# Centering a BitMap object in C++ Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printing

I managed to print a dataGridView using this method:

```
private:
   void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object ^ sender,
      System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs ^ e)
   {
      Bitmap^ bm = gcnew Bitmap(this->dataGridView1->Width, this->dataGridView1->Height);
            this->dataGridView1->DrawToBitmap(bm, Rectangle(0, 0, this->dataGridView1->Width, this->dataGridView1->Height));
            e->Graphics->DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
   }
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        printDialog1->ShowDialog();
        printDocument1->Print();
    }
```

I've tried to find some documentation on MSDN as to how I can accomplish centering of the DataGridView component in bitmap form, but I found nothing. How can I center it on the paper?

Comment: This ought to be pretty obvious, don't pass 0 to DrawImage().  The entire approach is hopelessly flawed, a bitmap copy of a grid is useless when the grid contains too many rows.  They all do.

Comment: I'll try that. You're the first to answer in a pretty long while. I've tried printing the data grid manually, but it's terribly complicated. If you have some useful printing articles, specifically to datagridview, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I already gave you advice on a good google query to find this kind of code.  Less than a day ago, not exactly 'a pretty long while'.  Ask for help from your team mates if you have trouble getting it working.  Or put this project on the shelf until you learn more about programming in c++/cli, you do seem to ask rather elementary questions about it.  Nothing a decent book can't fix.